# Showing some contacts multiple times in my App from phone book

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I'm getting same contact three or two times in my app this happening with some contacts not with every contacts. In my app everything is working as expected but when clicking on show contact from my it's shows three time same contact but in mobile phone contact stored only one time. I tried everything from my side but not able to solve this can any body please help me. Or is there any alternative way for same.

Here is my code:-

```
    @Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {


    try {


        db = new WhooshhDB(myContext);
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();

        ContentResolver cr = myContext.getContentResolver();

        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
        if ((cur != null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {

            while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {

                String id = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        ContactModel model = new ContactModel();

                        if (phoneNo.replaceAll("\\s", "").trim().length() > 7) {
                            model.name = name;
                            model.mobileNumber = phoneNo.replaceAll("\\s", "");
                            if (model.mobileNumber.contains("-")) {
                                model.mobileNumber = model.mobileNumber.replaceAll("-", "");
                            }
                            model.iconHexColor = AppConstant.getRandomSubscriptionHexColor(myContext);
                            if (!phoneNumber.equals(model.mobileNumber)) {
                                list.add(model);
                            }

                        }

                        Log.i("FetchContacts", "Name: " + name);
                        Log.i("FetchContacts", "Phone Number: " + phoneNo);
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
        }
        if (cur != null) {
            cur.close();
        }

        return AppConstant.SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing those "FetchContacts" logs for per contact per phone, so if a contact has multiple phones stored for her you'll see it printed multiple times (even if it's the same phone number).

If you have an app like Whatsapp installed, then almost always you'll see all phone number duplicated for each contact causing those logs to be printed more then once per contact.

Also, that's a slow and painful way of getting contacts w/ phones.
Instead you can simply query directly over Phones.CONTENT_URI and get all phones in the DB, and map them out into contacts by Contact-ID:

```
Map<String, List<String>> contacts = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

String[] projection = { Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };
Cursor cur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0); // contact ID
    String name = cur.getString(1); // contact name
    String data = cur.getString(2); // the actual info, e.g. +1-212-555-1234

    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + name + ", " + data);

    // add info to existing list if this contact-id was already found, or create a new list in case it's new
    String key = id + " - " + name;
    List<String> infos;
    if (contacts.containsKey(key)) {
        infos = contacts.get(key);
    } else {
        infos = new ArrayList<String>();
        contacts.put(key, infos);
    }
    infos.add(data);
}

// contacts will now contain a mapping from id+name to a list of phones.
// you can enforce uniqueness of phones while adding them to the list as well.
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of

```
while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
```

Change it to

```
if(cur.moveToFirst()){
list.clear();
```

Comment: Now i'm getting only 1 contact from phone book

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No It is giving one only contact from list